# how to escape my string when I calling a shell commend in perl?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk

I just want to use a awk command in my perl script  like follows:

```
$linum = `awk -F "%" '/^\s*kernel/{print NR}' < $grubFile`;
```

But it will say: `Unrecognized escape \s passed through at ./root line 36.`
How do I avoid that?  thank you.

Comment: Why are you calling `awk` from `perl` in the first place? Why not just do it directly in perl?

Comment: since a one line awk command is easier. :-)

Comment: @ikegami What the command is trying to do is print all line numbers that begin with spaces and the word kernel. Unfortunately, he is trying to use perl regex in awk, which doesn't use PCRE.

Comment: @ikegami: I'll see you and raise you a `$linum = IPC::System::Simple::capture('awk','-F%','/^\s*kernel/{print NR}',$grubFile);`

Comment: @jordanm, hi, this awk command just work well on my gawk with version: `GNU Awk 4.0.2`. So, maybe it knows `\s`. :-)

Comment: @ikegami, hi, you are right. I thought it will be easier when I decided using awk.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks :-). Must I open this file first like  `$fh = IO::File->new("< $filename")` if I don't want to pass this file as a parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$x = `... \s ...`;
```

makes no more sense than

```
$x = "... \s ...";
```

If you want the two characters `\` and `s`, you need to escape the `\` in double-quoted literals and similar. Just like you'd use

```
$x = "... \\s ...";
```

you need to use

```
$x = `... \\s ...`;
```

Note that you completely fail to properly escape the contents of `$grubFile` too. Your command will fail if the file name contains spaces. And consider what could happen instead if it contain other character special to shells, such as `|`.

As @ysth showed, the following is equivalent to your command:

```
awk -F% '/^\s*kernel/{print NR}' "$grubFile"
```

Getting rid of the input redirection means you could simply use

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );
my @line_nums = capturex('awk', '-F%', '/^\s*kernel/{print NR}', $grubFile);
chomp @line_nums;
```

By the way, it's not that hard to do it purely with Perl.

```
my @line_nums;
open(my $fh, '<', $grubFile) or die $!;
while (<$fh>) { 
   push @line_nums, $. if /^\s*kernel/;
}
```

Comment: Agreed with @ikegami as barmar, that since you are already in Perl, there really is no reason to go to awk.  Everything awk can do, Perl can do as well or better.  The only reason I could think of for using awk for this is if you don't have perl.

Comment: As stated in my comment above, `\s` doesn't have any significant meaning in POSIX extended regular expressions used by awk. It explains proper command usage in perl, but the awk command still likely doesn't do what is intended.

Comment: @jordan, `\s` works fine with the OP's `awk`, and that's all that really matters here, I think. But compatibility issues like this is why using just Perl is usually a good idea.